# Find the solution of given differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{x\,\mathrm dx+y\,\mathrm dy}{x\,\mathrm dy-y\,\mathrm dx}=\sqrt{\frac{a^2-x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}}$$

I tried figuring out $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ or $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$ from here but the integral was very heavy to handle.

Comment: try $y=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$

Comment: How did you arrive at that?

Comment: I dont think that works

Comment: It does; both the $LHS$ and $RHS$ of the differential equation become zero

Comment: Maple can solve this equation

Comment: Can this be solved without it?

Comment: oh sorry yes. I did a mistake. But how did you do this

Answer (score 0):

transform to the polar coordinates
$$(x, y)\rightarrow{(r\cos{\varphi}, r\sin{\varphi})}$$
then
$$xdx+ydy=r{dr}$$
$$xdy-ydx=r^{2}d\varphi$$
Thus, the equation is rewritten as
$$\frac{dr}{d\varphi}=\sqrt{a^{2}-r^{2}}$$
The solution is
$$r=a\sin{\varphi}$$
Thus
$$\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}=a\sin{\arctan{\frac{y}{x}}}=a\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}$$
Thus
$$ya-x^{2}-y^{2}=0$$
But I could have made a mistake somewhere.